# Batch file to tidy-up files per name

Tags: batch-file

I have the following folders:

```
Apple_folder
Pear_folder
Tomatoes_folder
```

Within `Apple_folder`, I have the following files:

```
Extracted-Apple_1.txt
Extracted-Apple_2.txt
Extracted-Pear_1.txt
Extracted-Pear_2.txt
Extracted-Apple_3.txt
Extracted-Tomatoes_1.txt
```

How do I move `Extracted-Pear_1.txt`, `Extracted-Pear_2.txt`, `Extracted-Tomatoes_1.txt` to their relevant folders, i.e. keep file name that contain `apple` under `Apple_folder`, etc.

Expected `Apple_folder` contents:

```
Extracted-Apple_1.txt
Extracted-Apple_2.txt
Extracted-Apple_3.txt
```

I am still a beginner in batch script, so not sure how to proceed?

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   echo %filename%    
   for /f "tokens=* delims=- _" %%f in (%filename%) do (
      if tokens==Pear move Extracted-Pear*.txt   "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\Pear_folder\"
      if tokens==Tomatoes move Extracted-Pear*.txt "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\Tomatoes_folder\"
   )
```

I am using this code to try to rename the files to avoid overwriting files with similar name in the destination folder.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A counter=0

@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do (  
set /A counter+=1
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=-_" %%f in ("%%a") do (
        move Extracted-%%f_*.txt "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\%%f_folder\Extracted-%%~nf_moved_!counter!.txt"
    )
)
```

only one file gets moved/renamed and then get an error message

```
"Cannot move multiple files to a single file."
```

Comment: Hint: use a [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop to iterate files and a [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) to split file names at the delimiters `-_`

Comment: read again the [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) documenation. Especially take a look at the examples at the bottom of the page. Your understanding of `tokens` and `delims` seems to be wrong.

Comment: You have unbalanced parentheses. I have formatted and indented your code to make it easier for you to notice that issue.

Comment: thanks @LotPings, I will need to do some research as I haven't done this type of operations before.

Comment: Thanks @Compo for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the missing `)` mentioned by Compo, there is a misunderstanding of how `tokens` and `delims` work. See [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for more information about that.

For the variable `filename` to work, you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected/30284028#30284028), but you can work without that by using the `for` variable (`%%a`) directly:

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
   for /f "tokens=2 delims=-_" %%f in ("%%a") do (
      ECHO move Extracted-%%f_*.txt  "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\%%f_folder\"
   )
)
```

A few explanations to the `tokens` and `delimiters` part:

The `for /f` loop disassembles the string into "tokens" by splitting it at the "delimiters":

`tokens=*` tells `for` to get the whole string, disregarding the delimiters (simplified version - in reality it's a bit more complicated).

`Extracted-Apple_1.txt` delimited by `-` and `_` gives you three tokens: `Extracted`, `Apple` and `.txt`, the first token named `%%f` (given by you), the next are just named with the following letters. Token 2 would be `%%g` and token 3 would be `%%h`.

Now it gets interesting: With `tokens=2` you tell `for` to just take the second token (which would go to `%%f`(!), as it's the first (and only) *returned* token)

So this leads to the `"tokens=2 delims=- _"` above.

**Note** I disabled the `move` command by just echoing it (for security and troubleshooting). Only when it works as intended, just remove the `ECHO` to enable the `move` command.

**Edit** to comply to the "no overwrite" request:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "counter=0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=-_" %%f in ("%%a") do call :FileMove "%%a" "%%f"
)
pause
goto :eof

:FileMove
set counter=0
:FileNext
if exist "C:\Users\NABIL\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script\%~2_folder\%~n1_moved__%counter%.txt" (
  set /a counter+=1
  goto :fileNext
)
md "C:\Users\NABIL\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script\%~2_folder\" 2>nul
MOVE "%~1" "C:\Users\NABIL\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script\%~2_folder\%~n1_moved__%counter%.txt"
goto :eof
```

I "outsourced" the renaming and moving to a subroutine, mainly because we need a `goto`, which is not possible within a code block. I also changed your destination file naming scheme to what I think you want, but I might be wrong - so please check that out.

Comment: Grateful for your help. Many thanks for the explanation. I ran it but it's giving an error:   _" was unexpected at this time..

Comment: Edited. (It was the space at `delims=- _` - I copy/pasted that from your question; We don't want the space as a delimiter - if we would want it, the space would have to be the last character)

Comment: It works after removing the space in delims. Thank you very much for your help @Stephan. You're a star!

Comment: I just have a bit of experience with `for` loops (the Terry Pratchett quote at the bottom of the linked site isn't there for no reason `;)`).

Comment: Would you be able to tell why the script above doesn't work? Thank you !

Comment: How does it not work? What doesn't happen although expected and what does happen although not expected?

Comment: When I move the files to relevant folders. The folders may have files with the same names and I don't want them overwritten (I believe MOVE can only overwrite), hence the need to rename them before moving them (adding moved_counter), e.g. Extracted-Tomatoes_moved_6.txt. when i ran the script, only when file gets renamed and moved as intended and then I get the error message "Cannot move multiple files to a single file." for the rest of files.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that. You need to check the destination  (`if exist "C:\Users\ABCD\Documents\%%f_folder\%%~nxa"), add a counter and loop until there is no such file.

Comment: [Search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+copy+without+overwrite)

Comment: The following script that I have just posted moves the files. However, it it does it twice on the first file. Extracted_Apple_1 becomes Extracted_Apple_moved_1 then Extracted_Apple_moved_4. Not sure where the glitch is?

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /A counter=0

@echo off
for %%a in (*.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=-_" %%f in ("%%a") do (
set /A counter+=1 
MOVE "%%a" "C:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\TESTING\Batch_script\%%f_folder\Extracted-%%~nf_moved__!counter!.txt"
    )
)
pause
```

Comment: the `for %%a in (*.txt)` processes (dynamically) all `*.txt` files If you create new matching files during that process, those may be processed also. Better: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.txt') do...`. The `dir /b *.txt` is executed once and the `for /f` loop processes its (static) output. You also forgot to check the existence at the destination before moving.

Comment: Could someone have a go at this and let me know please !!